# Como fazer upload com barra progresso usando qftp do pyside?

Tags: python, qftp

Como eu posso fazer upload usando o qftp do pyside? Eu já tenho um programa cliente ftp que faz o download. Abaixo segue o meu código do cliente ftp.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

import os, sys
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork

import ftp_rc

__version__ = '0.1'

class FtpWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FtpWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.isDirectory = {}
        self.currentPath = ''
        self.ftp = None
        self.outFile = None
        self.outUpFile = None

        ftpLoginLabel = QtGui.QLabel('&Usuário:')
        ftpPasswdLabel = QtGui.QLabel('&Senha:')
        ftpServerLabel = QtGui.QLabel("&Ftp server:")
        self.ftpLoginLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit('usuario')
        self.ftpLoginLineEdit.selectAll()
        self.ftpPasswdLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit('******')
        self.ftpPasswdLineEdit.selectAll()
        self.ftpPasswdLineEdit.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.ftpServerLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit('ftp.trolltech.com')
        ftpLoginLabel.setBuddy(self.ftpLoginLineEdit)
        ftpServerLabel.setBuddy(self.ftpServerLineEdit)
        ftpPasswdLabel.setBuddy(self.ftpPasswdLineEdit)

        self.statusLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Por favor entre com o USUÀRIO e SENHA e o SERVIDOR FTP")

        self.fileList = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        self.fileList.setEnabled(False)
        self.fileList.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.fileList.setHeaderLabels(("Nome", "Tamanho", "Propriétario", "Grupo", "Ultima Modificação"))
        self.fileList.header().setStretchLastSection(False)

        self.connectButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Connect")
        self.connectButton.setDefault(True)

        self.cdToParentButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.cdToParentButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/cdtoparent.png'))
        self.cdToParentButton.setEnabled(False)

        self.mkdirToParentButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.mkdirToParentButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/newFolder.png'))
        self.mkdirToParentButton.setEnabled(False)


        self.uploadButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Upload')
        self.uploadButton.setEnabled(False)

        self.downloadButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Download")
        self.downloadButton.setEnabled(False)

        self.quitButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit")

        buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox()
        buttonBox.addButton(self.uploadButton,
                            QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.ActionRole)
        buttonBox.addButton(self.downloadButton,
                QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.ActionRole)
        buttonBox.addButton(self.quitButton, QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.RejectRole)

        self.progressDialog = QtGui.QProgressDialog(self)

        self.fileList.itemActivated.connect(self.processItem)
        self.fileList.currentItemChanged.connect(self.enableDownloadButton)
        self.progressDialog.canceled.connect(self.cancelDownload)
        self.connectButton.clicked.connect(self.connectOrDisconnect)
        self.cdToParentButton.clicked.connect(self.cdToParent)
        self.mkdirToParentButton.clicked.connect(self.mkdirToParent)
        self.uploadButton.clicked.connect(self.uploadFile)
        self.downloadButton.clicked.connect(self.downloadFile)
        self.quitButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

        topLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        topLayout.addWidget(ftpLoginLabel)
        topLayout.addWidget(self.ftpLoginLineEdit)
        topLayout.addWidget(ftpPasswdLabel)
        topLayout.addWidget(self.ftpPasswdLineEdit)
        topLayout.addWidget(ftpServerLabel)
        topLayout.addWidget(self.ftpServerLineEdit)
        topLayout.addWidget(self.cdToParentButton)
        topLayout.addWidget(self.mkdirToParentButton)
        topLayout.addWidget(self.connectButton)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(topLayout)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.fileList)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.statusLabel)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("CLIENTE FTP")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/janela.png'))


    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(800, 600)

    def connectOrDisconnect(self):
        if self.ftp:
            self.ftp.abort()
            self.ftp.deleteLater()
            self.ftp = None

            self.fileList.setEnabled(False)
            self.cdToParentButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.downloadButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.uploadButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.connectButton.setEnabled(True)
            self.connectButton.setText("Connect")
            self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)

            return

        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor)

        self.ftp = QtNetwork.QFtp(self)
        self.ftp.commandFinished.connect(self.ftpCommandFinished)
        self.ftp.listInfo.connect(self.addToList)
        self.ftp.dataTransferProgress.connect(self.updateDataTransferProgress)

        self.fileList.clear()
        self.currentPath = ''
        self.isDirectory.clear()

        url = QtCore.QUrl(self.ftpServerLineEdit.text())
        if not url.isValid() or url.scheme().lower() != 'ftp':
            self.ftp.connectToHost(self.ftpServerLineEdit.text(), 21)
            self.ftp.login(user=self.ftpLoginLineEdit.text(), password=self.ftpPasswdLineEdit.text())
        else:
            self.ftp.connectToHost(url.host(), url.port(21))

            user_name = url.userName()
            if user_name:
                try:
                    # Python v3.
                    user_name = bytes(user_name, encoding='latin1')
                except:
                    # Python v2.
                    pass

                self.ftp.login(QtCore.QUrl.fromPercentEncoding(user_name), url.password())
            else:
                self.ftp.login()

            if url.path():
                self.ftp.cd(url.path())

        self.fileList.setEnabled(True)
        self.uploadButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.mkdirToParentButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.connectButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.connectButton.setText("Disconnect")
        self.statusLabel.setText("Conectando ao serveidor FTP %s..." % self.ftpServerLineEdit.text())

    def uploadFile(self):

        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Upload File', '.')
        data = QtCore.QFile(filename[0])
        #QtCore.QFile(QtCore.QIODevice.openMode(1))
        data.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
        #qdata = QtCore.QBitArray()
        qdata = QtCore.QByteArray(data.readAll())
        file = os.path.basename(filename[0])
        print data
        if not self.fileList.currentItem():
            self.ftp.put(qdata, file, self.ftp.TransferType())
        elif "." in self.fileList.currentItem().text(0):
            self.ftp.put(qdata, self.fileList.currentItem().parent().text(0) + file)
        elif self.fileList.currentItem().text(0) == "/":
            self.ftp.put(qdata, file)
            self.progressDialog.setLabelText("uploading %s..." % fileName)
            #self.downloadButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.progressDialog.exec_()
        else:
            print "erro"

    def downloadFile(self):
        fileName = self.fileList.currentItem().text(0)
        fn = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Salvar como...", None,
                                               "Todos os arquivos (*.*)")

        if not fn:
            return False

        if QtCore.QFile.exists(fn):
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "CLIENTE FTP",
                    "Ja existe uma arquivo chamado %s no diretorio "
                    "corrente." % fileName)
            return

        self.outFile = QtCore.QFile(fn)
        if not self.outFile.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly):
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "CLIENTE FTP",
                    "Unable to save the file %s: %s." % (fileName, self.outFile.errorString()))
            self.outFile = None
            return

        self.ftp.get(self.fileList.currentItem().text(0), self.outFile)

        self.progressDialog.setLabelText("Downloading %s..." % fileName)
        self.downloadButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.progressDialog.exec_()

    def cancelDownload(self):
        self.ftp.abort()

    def ftpCommandFinished(self, _, error):
        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)

        if self.ftp.currentCommand() == QtNetwork.QFtp.ConnectToHost:
            if error:
                QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "CLIENTE FTP",
                        "Nao foi possivel se conectar ao servidor ftp %s. Por favor "
                        "verifique se o nome do host esta correto." % self.ftpServerLineEdit.text())
                self.connectOrDisconnect()
                return

            self.statusLabel.setText("Conectado como %s em %s." % (self.ftpLoginLineEdit.text(),self.ftpServerLineEdit.text()))
            self.fileList.setFocus()
            self.downloadButton.setDefault(True)
            self.connectButton.setEnabled(True)
            return

        if self.ftp.currentCommand() == QtNetwork.QFtp.Login:
            self.ftp.list()

        if self.ftp.currentCommand() == QtNetwork.QFtp.Put:
            if error:
                self.statusLabel.setText('upload cancelado do %s.' % self)

        if self.ftp.currentCommand() == QtNetwork.QFtp.Get:
            if error:
                self.statusLabel.setText("download cancelado do %s." % self.outFile.fileName())
                self.outFile.close()
                self.outFile.remove()
            else:
                self.statusLabel.setText("Downloaded %s para o diretorio." % self.outFile.fileName())
                self.outFile.close()

            self.outFile = None
            self.enableDownloadButton()
            self.progressDialog.hide()
        elif self.ftp.currentCommand() == QtNetwork.QFtp.List:
            if not self.isDirectory:
                self.fileList.addTopLevelItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(["<empty>"]))
                self.fileList.setEnabled(False)

    def addToList(self, urlInfo):
        item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
        item.setText(0, urlInfo.name())
        item.setText(1, str(urlInfo.size()))
        item.setText(2, urlInfo.owner())
        item.setText(3, urlInfo.group())
        item.setText(4, urlInfo.lastModified().toString('dd MMM yyyy HH:MM'))

        if urlInfo.isDir():
            icon = QtGui.QIcon(':/images/dir.png')
        else:
            icon = QtGui.QIcon(':/images/file.png')
        item.setIcon(0, icon)

        self.isDirectory[urlInfo.name()] = urlInfo.isDir()
        self.fileList.addTopLevelItem(item)
        if not self.fileList.currentItem():
            self.fileList.setCurrentItem(self.fileList.topLevelItem(0))
            self.fileList.setEnabled(True)

    def processItem(self, item):
        name = item.text(0)
        if self.isDirectory.get(name):
            self.fileList.clear()
            self.isDirectory.clear()
            self.currentPath += '/' + name
            self.ftp.cd(name)
            self.ftp.list()
            self.cdToParentButton.setEnabled(True)
            self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor)

    def cdToParent(self):
        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor)
        self.fileList.clear()
        self.isDirectory.clear()

        dirs = self.currentPath.split('/')
        if len(dirs) > 1:
            self.currentPath = ''
            #self.cdToParentButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.ftp.cd('..')
        else:
            self.currentPath = '/'.join(dirs[:-1])
            self.ftp.cd(self.currentPath)

        self.ftp.list()

    def mkdirToParent(self):
        foldername = unicode(self.commandEdit.text())

    def updateDataTransferProgress(self, readBytes, totalBytes):
        self.progressDialog.setMaximum(totalBytes)
        self.progressDialog.setValue(readBytes)

    def enableDownloadButton(self):
        current = self.fileList.currentItem()
        if current:
            currentFile = current.text(0)
            self.downloadButton.setEnabled(not self.isDirectory.get(currentFile))
        else:
            self.downloadButton.setEnabled(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ftpWin = FtpWindow()
    ftpWin.show()
    sys.exit(ftpWin.exec_())
```

No código acima tem uma tentativa minha de fazer o upload mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Qual erro você obteve? Onde está localizada a sua tentativa? Tente colocar mais detalhes para o entendimento do problema e explicar como você tentou resolver. Ajudará o pessoal a compreender melhor :)

Comment: Por favor coloque o código todo num [gist](https://gist.github.com/) ou num [repositório](https://github.com/new) do github e coloque aqui apenas o trecho relevante à pergunta. Ficará mais fácil apra alguém dar o suporte para você.

Comment: Seria possível você simplificar o código para mostrar **somente** o trecho relevante? (i.e. tirar toda a parte de Qt, etc, de modo que fique simples pra quem for responder reproduzir o seu problema) O ideal seria colocar o menor programa possível que ainda demonstre o problema que você está tendo.

Comment: Boa tarde pessoal na verdade o que eu estou precisando é de um exemplo de como fazer upload de arquivos usando a função **put** da biblioteca **qftp** eu pesquisei na internet mais não conseguir achar exemplos que explicam como usar essa função!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No **pyside** você tem um method chamado **QProgressBar**, ele faz exatamente o que você precisa.

```
self.client = QtNetwork.QFtp()
self.connect(self.client, QtCore.SIGNAL('stateChanged(int)'), self.updateStatus)
self.connect(self.client, QtCore.SIGNAL('dataTransferProgress(int,int)'), self.updateProgress)
self.client.connectToHost('ftp.avelino.xxx')
self.client.login("ting","moomin")

def updateProgress(self, position, total):
    print(str(position) + "::" + str(total))
```

O method **updateProgress** retorna exatamente o que você precisa, onde esta/total.

referencia: http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QProgressBar.html

Comment: Muito obrigado, mais você poderia tbm me dar exemplo de como fazer upload usando **QFtp** do **PySide**?